# How to prepare Cygwin environment on windows 10 for compilation of Ada GNATColl library

Tags: windows, postgresql, cygwin, ada

After successful installation of Ada 2012 on windows 10 (with AdaCore-Download-2016-07-14_0729 package) I didn't find how to step forward to add database driver support to Ada.  I found GNATColl library and download package but I didn't really found any description how to prepare cygwin envirnment to compile it.
Do i need to install gcc toolchain with ada support, postgres and python inside cygwin again or just prepare PATH to /cygdrive/* locations in windows ?

Comment: What has been used to compile `AdaCore` ? If cygwin was not used you can not use the cygwin libraries and tools with it.

Comment: As I remember, 5+ years ago we installed GNAT with the Windows installer, which put GNAT’s %prefix%\bin on the Windows PATH, and when we started a Cygwin shell, lo and behold GNAT’s $prefix/bin (i.e. translated to Cygwin conventions) was on the Cygwin PATH.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Compiler, source, lib's and everything else is already installed in the windows and I use gcc for GNAT installed by AdaCore installer. 
Only "make" tool was missing in the cygwin itself. In the moment I successfully build gnatcoll lib, but not yet with postgres. 
./configure --prefix=/cygdrive/h/ada/install --without-python
make 
make install

Comment: well, I think using "make" from cygwin is somehow messing with this "cygdrive" path names, because obviously was not used correctly. If I "configure" postgres " --with-postgresql=/cygdrive/h/Ada/PostgreSQL/9.4" , configure recognize this path as correct, but make on the end complain there is no library "-lpq".

Answer (score 5):

**Installing ADA 2012 on Windows 10 64bit**

After installation of base Ada package we got all what we need to develop in Ada with IDE environment (GPS) and GNAT mingw environment with debugger (GDB). 
On windows OS only 32bit installation is supported. Windows can be 64bit edition.

http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations

**1. Prerequisites :**

**1.1. Install Python 2.7 for windows  - 32bit**

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
Select 32bit windows edition: Windows x86 MSI installer 
Add C:\Python27 to PATH on windows.

**1.2. Install PostgreSQL 32bit**

Gcc compiler for GNAT in AdaCore and external libraries must be in the same format. 
Postgres libraries in the 32bit format are available: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload
File: postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-binaries.zip
Unzip postgres into folder where build will get libraries : 
Folder: H:\Ada\PostgreSQL953
For compiling client applications we do not need whole server installed, just libraries in proper format.

**1.3. Install Cygwin**

Download from: https://cygwin.com/install.html
Take setup-x86.exe file, this is 32bit version of cygwin.

**1.3.1. Install make**

If you forget to install anything on the first setup run, just run setup again and add missing package.
Start  setup-x86.exe again and search for »make« package in »Devel«, mark it for installation and proceed with »Next«. Package will be installed in the existing installation.

**2. Install Ada**

**2.1. Install GNAT Gpl – base Ada package**

```
File:  gnat-gpl-2016-x86-windows-bin.exe
Install with »Run as administrator« .
Destination folder. H:\Ada\GNAT\2016
```

**2.2. Install Win32Ada**

```
D:\Install\Ada\AdaCore-Download-2016-07-14_0729\x86-windows\adagpl-2016\win32ada
File: win32ada-gpl-2016-x86-windows-bin.exe
Install with »Run as administrator« .
Destination folder:   H:\Ada\GNAT\2016
```

**2.3. Install GtkAda**

```
D:\Install\Ada\AdaCore-Download-2016-07-14_0729\x86-windows\adagpl-2016\gtkada
File: gtkada-gpl-2016-x86-windows-bin.exe
Install with »Run as administrator« .
Destination folder: H:\Ada\GtkAda
```

**2.4. Install AWS - ada web server**

```
D:\Install\Ada\AdaCore-Download-2016-07-14_0729\x86-windows\adagpl-2016\aws\sources
File:  aws-gpl-2016-src.tar.gz unzip file to working folder.

Now execute next commands in cygwin environment :

$ make setup build
$ make --prefix=/Ada/GNAT/2016 install 

AWS should be installed on GNAT compiler root folder by default. 
http://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/building_aws.html
```

**2.5. Install GNATColl library with postgres interface**

```
D:\Install\Ada\AdaCore-Download-2016-07-14_0729\x86-windows\adagpl-2016\gnatcoll\sources\

File gnatcoll-gpl-2016-src.tar.gz unzip file to working folder.

**Now execute next commands in cygwin environment :**

$ ./configure --prefix=/Ada/GNAT/2016 –with-postgresql=H:/ADA/PostgreSQL953/lib
```

*Be very careful with path to postgresql lib folder.*

```
--------- Summary for GNAT Components --------------
Shared libraries:       yes (default: static)
Gtk+:                   yes (requires pkg-config and gtkada.gpr)
PostgreSQL:             yes -LH:/ADA/PostgreSQL953/lib (see --with-postgresql)
Sqlite:                 embedded  (see --with-sqlite)
Projects:               yes
Other components where on "no".
```

**Manually edit file:  gnatcoll_shared.gpr**

I am not sure if this is really necessary, but I did this clean up.
Clean broken lines where RETURN character divide »end of line«, for example:

```
Python_Version :=  "27
";
```

*Change to :*

```
Python_Version :=  "27";
```

*Execute make commands in cygwin*

```
$ make 

$ make install
```

In case of errors, reset build environment with »make clean« command and restart with "configure".